# How to search string from table of criteria and return value from it?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm need to return value from search on string that is set from table of criteria. The table is contain the partial string which is use to look into a string.

```
Wksht1                                 Wksht2(Criteria)
A              Result                  A      B      C      Result
Change Roller  Type 1(from Criteria)   Change Roller        Type 1
Pkg NG                                 Pkg    NG            Type 2
Lid NG                                 Lid    Dent          Type 3
```

The result should be in Wksht1 in result column.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you so much in advance.

Edit:

The longer string edition.

```
Wksht1                                 
A                                       Result
Assemble NG and Lid dent                Type 3
Change roller and do camera setting     Type 1
Change spec and lid are dent            Type 3
```

I have to separate the keyword for better recognition.

Comment: please confirm there are four columns being A, B, C and Result on your Wksht2? You want Type 1 to be returned for `Change Roller` is based on what criteria? Also what have you tried so far as I am sure you can find similar cases online or even here.

Comment: Most of cases I look online only consist of 1 dimensional array. The criteria table should be A1+B1+C1 (contain in string)  then return the result of Type 1. The string to for can be longer than provide here.

Comment: are you able to update your sample data with more realistic examples (longer strings with possible variations), and provide more expected results based on the new sample data? you can use this [tool](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) to import a sample sheet and then paste the converted table to your post.

Comment: I have edit the explanation to include the actual record. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Are the strings all space separated or is there any special symbol such as comma? Also what if there is also "pkg" in the first string, should it return type2 or type3? Or there will be no such scenario?

Comment: The string is space separated, like normal sentences. No, the keyword must be consecutive as per row, like keyword A1 & B1 & C1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have the following **named ranges**:

- **C_A** being the key words in Column A on your criteria sheet;
- **C_B** being the key words in Column B on your criteria sheet;
- **C_C** being the key words in Column C on your criteria sheet;
- **Result** being the types in Column Result on your criteria sheet.

Enter the following formula in Cell `B2` in your result sheet (suppose your list starts from Cell A2):

```
=IFERROR(LOOKUP(1,1/(IFERROR((SEARCH("#"&C_B&"#",MID(SUBSTITUTE(A2," ","# #"),SEARCH("#"&C_A&"#","#"&SUBSTITUTE(A2," ","# #")&"#")+LEN(C_A)+1,2^15)&"#")>IF(LEN(C_C)=0,0,1/ISNUMBER(SEARCH("#"&C_C&"#",SUBSTITUTE(MID(A2,SEARCH(C_B,A2)+LEN(C_B),2^15)," ","# #")&"#"))))*ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,ROWS(Result))),0)),Result),"No Match")
```

Please note it is an **array formula** so you need to confirm it by pressing **Ctrl**+**Shift**+**Enter** after entered the above formula in the formula bar.

Drag it down to apply across as shown below:

[image: Solution]

Sample data for testing:

```
| Strings                                       |
|-----------------------------------------------|
| Assemble NG and Lid dent                      |
| Change roller and do camera setting           |
| Change spec and lid are dent                  |
| dent liD roller changeable                    |
| Test1 xxx lid xx pkG x ng xxxxx xxxxxxx Test3 |
| xxx Test1 x pkG xxxxxx  xxx Test2 test3       |
| Change xxxxxx test1 xxx test2 xx Test4        |
| Change Test1 xxxx Lid xxxx NG xxx controller  |
| Pkg Ngyuent Test1 Test21                      |
```

The logic is to add a unique symbol such as hashtag `#` to each keyword and convert them to `#keyword#`, then search the first column of keywords through the string and return the position of the word if it exists, then search the second column of keywords from the rest of the string from previous search, and return the position of the second keyword if it exists. Then find out if there a third keyword in the remaining string. If so return the corresponding result.

> Here comes one **limitation** of my solution which might be a deal breaker. For instance, if you already have `A-Test1; B-Test2` as  one keywords combination for **Type4**, and have another combination of `A-Test1; B-Test2; C-Test3` for **Type5**, the combination that has less keywords must be located in a row above the combination that has three keywords. Reason being my formula will always return the combination that comes last on the criteria sheet if the first two keywords are identical. A workaround is to rearrange your criteria sheet to make sure 3-keyword combinations are always come after the 2-keyword combinations.

Let me know if you have any questions. Cheers :)

Comment: Thanks for this answer. It really help me on this matter.

Comment: @zefy2k5 No worries. I sense the actual case might not be as complicated as I anticipated so my solution might be over-complicated. However if you are an experienced user of excel you can modify the solution or take the useful bits to suit your situation.

Answer (score 0):

This situation can be handled very quickly with a VLookup formula. it seems the string mentioned in column A & B of wroksheet2 is the substring of column A of worksheet 1

```
You want to search the of the string of column A of the worksheet in column A, B of worksheet2
Step-1: concatenate the column A & B of worksheet2 into column C as =concatenate(A1," ",B1)
Step-2: apply vlookup in the column B of the worksheest1 to get the result from the worksheet2 
formula can be applied in B1 as 
=vlookup(A1,Sheet2!C:Sheet2!D,2,0)
```

you will get the result in b column of worksheet1

Comment: I'm cannot combine the keyword since the real situation are based on the separate keyword. I have edit the explanation for better understanding.